# Windows Suspending PostgreSQL Process

Tags: postgresql, windows-server, connectivity

Scenario:

- Customer’s system
- VM running Windows Server Standard 2019, 16GB RAM, Intel Xeon Gold 5122 @ 3.6GHz (2 processors 4 virtual processors)
- PostgreSQL starts and runs fine for 5 minutes - 2 hours
- Postgres stops accepting new connections but existing connections continue to function.
- Postgres log shows `worker took too long to start; canceled` and nothing else.
- Windows Task Manager shows multiple Postgres processes (like usual) with a single Postgres process suspended (Not normal)
- Trying to stop the Postgres service just hangs for a while unless you “end task” on the suspended process.

I've been googling for several hours and am not finding anything.

Comment: Any Anti-Virus software active?

Comment: Examine the PostgreSQL log for more information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, AV is active though I don't have a connection to the server at the moment to check what it is for sure. Malware Bytes (I think).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I updated the question to indicate that the log shows what I already posted and nothing else.

Comment: If that hasn't been done yet, you should exclude the Postgres binaries and data directory from the AV.

Comment: That log entry is not a PostgreSQL message, it must be a Windows message from starting PostgreSQL. You have to locate the PostgreSQL log and look there.

Comment: It is a PostgreSQL log message. It comes from the log file in ./data/logs and seems to be generated when a client is trying to connect and PostgreSQL is trying to start a new worker process to handle it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it was the AV. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.